# Visual Studio 2008 cannot find header that is in build path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Edit: I do not understand WHY this fixed the problem, but I added the include and lib directories to Tools>Options>Projects&Solutions>VC++Directories and it built perfectly.

I'm trying to compile a c++ example project distributed by Autodesk in VS 2008.

The error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'max.h': No such file or directory

Previously when I have encountered this error it has been caused by forgetting to specify the location of a header in Project>Properties>Configuration>C++>General. However, the path is definitely there this time and I can navigate to that directory and open max.h manually.

This project builds a DLL instead of an executable. Could that cause this?

So as an experiment I wrote the complete path for max.h after the #include directive in the source. Compile successful!

```
Linking failed:
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'edmodel.lib'
```

Yes edmodel.lib is located in a directory specified in Project>Properties>Configuration>Linker>General.

Any insight into what might be going on here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make sure right configuration is selected when setting project properties**
Make sure you have set correct path in *C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories* for all configurations (Debug, Release, some custom if you have any...). When path to directory with headers is set properly, you can't have any problems with including them.

**2. When using libraries, you have to specify path to these libraries but names of libraries you are going to use as well**
You wrote, that you have set *Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories*. But make sure that you have specified name of library in *Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* as well. You should append the name of library at the end: `;edmodel.lib`

Comment: I do not understand WHY this fixed the problem, but I added the include and lib directories to Tools>Options>Projects&Solutions>VC++Directories and it built perfectly.

Comment: It means that Paths to include and library directories that you have set under properties of project were probably incorrect. In newer versions of VS is VC++ Directories option marked as deprecated.

Comment: P.S. Thank you so much for answering. I've posted to 3 different fora in the past couple of days and you are the first person to answer me.